# How to split months between a start date and end date from a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to set up a stored procedure in SQL Server which creates month by month currency exchange rates based on a start and end date per currency.

The following is the format of the table I want to work with:

```
Table 1 (Input Table)
+------------+------------+------------+
| Start Date |  End Date  |  Currency  |
+------------+------------+------------+
| 01/01/2016 | 30/05/2016 |   EUR      | 
| 01/03/2017 | 31/05/2017 |   BDT      | 
+------------+------------+------------+
```

From the above table, I want the stored procedure to give an output like this:

```
Table 2 (Desired result from sql script)
Date        Currency
---------------------
01/01/2016  EUR
01/02/2016  EUR
01/03/2016  EUR
01/04/2016  EUR
01/05/2016  EUR
01/03/2017  BDT
01/04/2017  BDT
01/05/2017  BDT
```

Then I want to join these two outputs to give a final table like this:

```
Final Table (Join on Table 1 and 2) 

Start Date  End Date    Split Date  Currency    Exchange Rate
-------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2016  30/05/2016  18/01/2016  EUR         x
01/01/2016  30/05/2016  18/02/2016  EUR         z
01/01/2016  30/05/2016  18/03/2016  EUR         h
01/01/2016  30/05/2016  18/04/2016  EUR         g
01/01/2016  30/05/2016  18/05/2016  EUR         a
01/03/2017  31/05/2018  01/03/2017  BDT         b
01/03/2017  31/05/2018  01/04/2017  BDT         c
01/03/2017  31/05/2018  01/05/2017  BDT         f
```

I have found some solutions on stackoverflow like this:

```
declare @StartDate date = '20170401'
      , @EndDate   date = '20170731';

;with Months as 
(
    select top (datediff(month, @startdate, @enddate) + 1) 
        [Month] = dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number) -1, @StartDate),
        MonthEnd = dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by number), @StartDate))   
    from 
        master.dbo.spt_values   
    order by 
        [Month] 
) 
select * from Months;
```

However, this only uses hard coded start and end dates. I want the start and end dates to be taken per row from the an input table like the one mentioned at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. You provided several tables of sample data, but no DDL and no explanation of how the data is transformed from one table to the next.

Comment: I cant see where the interim table is used in the final result. Final result appears to be every day between start and end dates from first table. The example you found with CTE can easily use dates from your source table rather than fixed dates if you need to, but I don't think that will answer your underlying question.

Comment: Also, your end date for EUR is before your start date.

Comment: The question has quite a few confusing things and does not have adequate information:1> Could you provide your input participating table DDLs and some sample data, and then provide what output you are looking for rather than providing what your intermediate data looks like? 2> Not sure from where you are getting the ExchangeRate values. 3> Your EndDate for EUR seems to be older than your StartDate. Could you please edit the question with these details?

Comment: 4> Also, could you please explain why your output SplitDate for EUR 18th of every month with respect to its StartsDate = 18/01/2016, but for BDT it is 1st of every month even though it's StartDate = 19/03/2017 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got the idea of what you are trying to do. This will do it all in one query.

First set up your test data (correcting your typo where enddate was < startdate)

```
create table xchg(startdate date, enddate date, currency varchar(3))
insert xchg values ('2016-01-18','2016-05-30','EUR')
,('2017-03-19','2017-05-31','BDT')
```

Then a recursive query picking out each anniversary between the two dates. Don't know where you are getting the exchange rate from, but you should be able to add it to the this.

```
;with splits as
(
    select *, startdate as split from xchg
    union all
    select startdate, enddate, currency, 
        dateadd(m,1,split) 
    from splits
    where dateadd(m,1,split) <= enddate
)
select * from splits order by currency, split
```

Result is:

```
startdate   enddate     currency    split
2017-03-19  2017-05-31  BDT         2017-03-19
2017-03-19  2017-05-31  BDT         2017-04-19
2017-03-19  2017-05-31  BDT         2017-05-19
2016-01-18  2016-05-30  EUR         2016-01-18
2016-01-18  2016-05-30  EUR         2016-02-18
2016-01-18  2016-05-30  EUR         2016-03-18
2016-01-18  2016-05-30  EUR         2016-04-18
2016-01-18  2016-05-30  EUR         2016-05-18
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This one worked for me. The exchange rates will be coming from an external source.

I corrected the typos accroding to your feedback as well :)